# Are you also supposed to spell out *decimal* numbers under 100?

Tags: numbers

I know that you are supposed to "spell out" numbers under 100 in texts, such as:

> Sue had seventy-five cows.

Rather than:

> Sue had 75 cows.

But what about numbers under 100 which are not "full" numbers but decimals?

> Betty had fifty point seven apples.

That just looks weird. Surely, for such cases, you do:

> Betty had 50.7 apples.

... right?

Comment: There is no "supposed to": this is completely a matter of opinion. There are no rules, merely conventions and style guides for publication.

Comment: In most style guides, the advice regarding spelling out numbers that fall below some threshold (such as 100 or 11) applies only to integers (or in some cases to simple fractions or to integers with simple fractions attached to them). Beyond that, many style guides also distinguish between integers used in general count situations (such as "three people") and integers used in conjunction with units of measure (such as "3 milligrams"). I have never come across a style guide that recommends spelling out numbers that include decimals—and I've dealt with a lot of style guides.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the rules for APA, as reported by this [PDF](https://llu.instructure.com/courses/789013/files/23333485/download?verifier=6ytfpQHYKK9ekOd4tMgWN4jsOJ2T8RYQ3Aq4zSOj&wrap=1):

> **Use numbers to express**:
>   a. numbers 10 and above
>   [...]
>   d. numbers that represent statistical or mathematical functions, fractional or decimal quantities, percentages, ratios, and percentiles and quartiles

...

> **Use words to express**:
>   [...]
>   b. common fractions [one-fifth of the class; two-thirds majority]

So for your example you would write  *50.7 apples*.

Comment: Was this an APA question? :)

Comment: I don’t see why a psychology association should be regarded as authoritative here in the context of cows and apples. A organization’s style guide isn’t stipulating, or even recommending, how the public should communicate. It is, in contrast, recommending how this particular group of professionals should communicate in their highly specialised area of expertise.  **That said**, the particular “rules” you have quoted look to be in agreement with the common way ordinary folk would approach this sort of thing. (That is, your answers are generally right, but the reasons you give are wrong.)

Comment: The APA is a widely-cited style guide. I am not sure why people are acting like the citation is out-of-place.

Comment: Just how do you define 0.7 apples?